# Any API or something which allows to post received whatsApp message in website

Tags: javascript, php, whatsapi

Is there any way I can post my received whatsApp messages to my website. Basically I am creating a buy and sell site which allows buyer and seller to post 
ads from their whatsapp application too.

The process is a user will send us a message on our whatsapp number with all the details about it ads and we will directly post it on our website without requiring the user to log in our website and post their. Is there any way through which this process can be facilitated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nope, WhatsApp don't give out an API because all the messages are not centralised, instead being on individual devices.

Check here https://www.quora.com/WhatsApp-Why-doesnt-WhatsApp-have-an-API

Comment: what about whatsapp business account? what is that? and what can we do with whatsapi?

Comment: What's API became Chat API, and that is also now dead,

Comment: and what is whatsapp business account?